# Postgres - best way to add new rows into tables from a different table

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, merge, upsert

Scenario: I have a publication database, with the following tables:

- `publication` contains info about every book in the database.
- `keyword` list all the predefined terms that identify the publications.
- `publication_keyword` is a lookup table that matches publication and keywords.
- `new_publication_keyword` is a lookup table that contains new matches between publication and keywords.

I need to add the rows from `new_publication_keyword` into `publication_keyword`, avoiding to add already existing rows.

Here is the DDL that creates the scenario, in a test schema

```
SET search_path = test;

drop table publication_keyword;
drop table publication;
drop table keyword;
drop table new_publication_keyword;

CREATE TABLE publication (
  id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(1024),
  CONSTRAINT publication_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE keyword (
  id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  label VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT keyword_list_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE publication_keyword (
  publication_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  keyword_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX publication_keyword_code_idx ON publication_keyword
  USING btree (keyword_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX publication_keyword_pubid_idx ON publication_keyword 
  USING btree (publication_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE TABLE new_publication_keyword (
  publication_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  keyword_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX new_publication_keyword_code_idx ON new_publication_keyword 
 USING btree (keyword_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX new_publication_keyword_pubid_idx ON new_publication_keyword 
 USING btree (publication_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

insert into publication values ('EAN13CODE1001','Title 1');
insert into publication values ('EAN13CODE1002','Title 2');
insert into publication values ('EAN13CODE1003','Title 3');

insert into keyword values ('KWCODE0001','Keyword 1');
insert into keyword values ('KWCODE0002','Keyword 2');

insert into publication_keyword values ('EAN13CODE1001', 'KWCODE0001');
insert into publication_keyword values ('EAN13CODE1002', 'KWCODE0001');

insert into new_publication_keyword values ('EAN13CODE1001', 'KWCODE0001');
insert into new_publication_keyword values ('EAN13CODE1003', 'KWCODE0001');
insert into new_publication_keyword values ('EAN13CODE1003', 'KWCODE0002');
```

I would like to know which is the best strategy to use when each table contains millions of rows. Currently, I am using the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query, excluding all the existing rows, but it is a very slow solution:

```
insert into publication_keyword (publication_id, keyword_id)
  select npw.publication_id, npw.keyword_id from new_publication_keyword npw left outer join 
   publication_keyword pw on npw.publication_id = pw.publication_id and npw.keyword_id = pw.keyword_id
   where pw.publication_id is null
```

I would like to use the `INSERT` with the `ON CONFLICT` clause, but to use it, I need to create a PRIMARY KEY on the publication_keyword table, using a lot of disk space for this new index:

```
-- Not working with the current schema, need to add a PK on publication_keyword 
insert into publication_keyword (publication_id, keyword_id)
  select publication_id, keyword_id from new_publication_keyword
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

So, what is the best solution to add the new rows ?

Comment: The best solution ***is*** to add a primary (or unique) key. if those values should be unique this should be enforced in the database anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a disk space problem -- which is a little confusing because you already have lots of indexes on your tables.

That said, your solution wants three indexes.  I would suggest only two:

```
CREATE TABLE new_publication_keyword (
  publication_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  keyword_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (publication_id, keyword_id)
);

CREATE INDEX new_publication_keyword_code_idx ON new_publication_keyword 
 USING btree (keyword_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

With the primary key defined, you don't need a separate index for `publication_id`.

And, all that said, I don't understand why you are using strings for your ids.  Integers would be more efficient.  Let me guess that you already have a key for each table.  You can create a synthetic one in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE publications (
  publication_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  my_id VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(1024),
  CONSTRAINT unq_publication UNIQUE (my_id)
);

CREATE TABLE keywords (
  keyword_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  my_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
  label VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT unq_keyword_list UNIQUE (my_id)
);
```

Then you have:

```
CREATE TABLE new_publication_keywords (
  publication_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES publications(publication_id),
  keyword_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES keywords(keyword_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (publication_id, keyword_id)
);

CREATE INDEX new_publication_keyword_code_idx ON new_publication_keyword 
 USING btree (keyword_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Although the base tables are bigger -- both because there is an addition 4-byte serial id and an additional index, the association table is much smaller.

In your version, each row is up to 24 + 12 + 1 + 1 = 38 bytes.  In this version each row is 8 bytes.  This difference also affects the indexes; plus, indexes on fixed sized keys are usually a bit more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions about the indexes, I will create a new PK and drop the publication_id index. I am using string code instead of numeric ones because the codes come from external databases and we need to keep the same code in the various systems.

Comment: @NicolaLepetit . . . You should keep the code in the base tables and use a serial id internal to the database for the links in this database.  You are wasting a lot of space managing strings -- assuming the average string has 4 or more characters.